# Does WinRT/Metro support multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I want to create an application that has multiple touch surfaces, preferably using the Metro/WinRT APIs. However, much of what I've read indicates that Metro is confined to a single (primary?) monitor. Is that true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Metro style applications are full screen, single screen only.  There is no way to have a dual-screen application.

Comment: That sucks almost defies all the multiscreen progress. I hope MS decides to improve that, it's frustrating not being able to run apps on multiple screens.

Comment: Multi-screen support was added to Windows 8.1 for Store apps. See my other answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested Win8 with multiple monitors. The metro interface is only ever available on a single monitor, with the othe always displaying the 'traditional' desktop. You can switch which monitor displays the metro UI, but cannot render it on both.

Comment: Thanks, time to write MS a message that this sucks.

Comment: @Lothar don't forget to write Samsung that they should develop a dualhead galaxy tab ;)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft heard this request and added multi-monitor support to Windows 8.1. See the [Windows.UI.ViewManagement namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.aspx), specifically the [ProjectionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager.aspx) and [ApplicationViewSwitcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewswitcher.aspx) classes. There's also a [Projection sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d) for this.